# ogr2ogr losing all ExtendedData attributes of KML

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert a KML to a shapefile using ogr2ogr, but whenever I do, I end up with only blank `Name` and `Description` fields on the elements, losing the `ExtendedData` that is attached in the KML. A number of old answers here suggest that this should've been solved with GDAL 1.9.2; I'm on GDAL 1.11.2, so that shouldn't be a problem. How do I get the ExtendedData information into my shapefile?

Comment: Can you share some sample data? Notice also that there are two KML drivers: http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html and http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html and LIBKML has more features.

Comment: Add a beginning of what you get with `ogrinfo -al your.kml` into your question.